# How can I get a Perl script to accept parameters from both STDIN and command line arguments?

Tags: perl

Inspired by this U&L Q&A titled: "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171150/back-to-back-pipes-into-a-command". How could one parse both input via STDIN and via command line arguments to a Perl script?

For example I'd like a script that can consume input parameters from both STDIN and via command line arguments:

```
$ command | my_command.pl arg1 arg2
```

And the output of `command` would be

```
arg3
arg4
...
```

So while `my_command.pl` is running, it would be aware of the parameters arg1, arg2, arg3, and arg4.

Comment: I'm a bit uncertain what you're waning. This sounds like it satisfies your requirements: `perl -e 'push(@ARGV, "/dev/stdin"); while(<>) { print }' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2`

Comment: @Patrick - I wanted a example Perl script similar to what was mentioned in the referenced U&L Q&A that could take input from either STDIN or cmd line args, or both. The OP there didn't include an example and when I searched for an example I found none that demonstrated both aspects, so I couldn't resist the puzzle and made one.

Comment: I think it might be easier to do this with a wrapper using `xargs` rather than from Perl itself.

Comment: @muru - I wasn't looking for the easiest way to do this, I simply wanted to construct a surrogate question for my answer. 8-). Since searching for examples showed none, it seemed like a odd hole on the Internet that there were no good examples for using Perl in this manner.

Comment: Which  makes me wonder if there's a module lurking in the dark corners of CPAN which has `xargs`-like functionality.

Comment: @muru - I'd bet money that there is. But don't knock yourself out for this. I originally wanted to create this Q purely b/c there wasn't a decent example. If I had to guess, there's likely a module for constructing Perl scripts as Unix cli tools which offers this out of the box, even though you can do it yourself as I've done. The  other one to look into would be and of the modules that parse command line arguments. I'd suspect that they too can do this.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for this functionality.  `my_command.pl arg1 arg2 $(command)` does what you want, with the added benefit of not consuming stdin.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - this was purely an exercise in how one could do it, not whether it was needed or not. As I stated, there was a Q that mentioned doing this on U&L, but did not include any example code showing the parsing of input. So I conceived of the method shown in my answer below, and thought it worthwhile to share on the Internet, given I did not find full examples showing both.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - the original OP to the Q I reference above, showed this: `echo "y" | echo "response" | ./command.pl` which does not work for obvious reasons! But he wanted to understand how one could pipe this type of output to a Perl script. In my work to test the various solutions to that Q I needed a `command.pl`, this is the fall out of that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rather easy to do using perl's [diamond operator](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/learn/ch06_02.htm)

```
push(@ARGV, "/dev/stdin");
while(<>) {
  print;
}
```

For example:

```
$ echo A > a
$ echo B > b
$ echo C | perl test.pl a b
A
B
C
```

Unfortunately this does rely on `/dev/stdin`, but is still fairly portable.

Comment: I should've added the examples that the OP showed to my Q. He was ultimately trying to make this work: `echo -e "response\ny" | ./command.pl` and I wanted my own `./command.pl` to test the various methods for passing data in. I wanted a script that could take just the arguments via STDIN + ARGV, not the contents of ARGV as files.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with the following Perl script which reads data from either STDIN or command line arguments, or both.

#### The script

```
$ cat command.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

if ( -t STDIN and not @ARGV ) {
    print "\n" ."USAGE" . "\n";
    print       "=====" . "\n";
    print "#1:\t $0 <arg1>..<argN>\n";
    print "#2:\t <commands> | $0\n";
    print "#3:\t <commands> | $0 <arg1>..<argN>\n\n";
    exit 1;
}

if ( not -t STDIN ) { 
    print "\n" . "STDIN ARGS" . "\n";
    print        "==========" . "\n";
    print while (<STDIN>); 
    print "\n";
}

if (@ARGV) { 
    print "\n" . "ARGV ARGS" . "\n";
    print        "=========" . "\n";
    foreach (@ARGV) { 
        print "$_\n"; 
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

#### How it works

The script makes use of both `@ARGV` and `<STDIN>`, keying off of whether they're defined or not. If neither is defined then it shows usage and bails out.

#### Test script

To test it I put together this secondary script called `tests.bash` which runs the above script using a variety of ways to pass input into it. **NOTE:** That the tests are labelled T00 through T10.

```
$ cat tests.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo ""
echo ""

echo "====================================="
echo "T00: no input"
./command.pl
echo "====================================="
echo ""

# http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html
echo "====================================="
echo "T01: 2 args w/ pipe via cmd list '(..) | ...' aka. subshell"
( echo "pipearg1"; echo "pipearg2"; ) | ./command.pl
echo "====================================="
echo ""

# http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#CODEBLOCKREF
echo "====================================="
echo "T02: 2 args w/ pipe via inline group '{..} | ...' aka. code block"
{ echo "pipearg1"; echo "pipearg2"; } | ./command.pl
echo "====================================="
echo ""

echo "====================================="
echo "T03: 2 cli args 'cmd A1 A2'"
./command.pl argv1 argv2
echo "====================================="
echo ""

echo "====================================="
echo "T04: T01 + T03"
( echo "pipearg1"; echo "pipearg2"; ) | ./command.pl argv1 argv2
echo "====================================="
echo ""

echo "====================================="
echo "T05: T02 + T03"
{ echo "pipearg1"; echo "pipearg2"; } | ./command.pl argv1 argv2
echo "====================================="
echo ""

echo "====================================="
echo "T06: echo with newline: $'..\n..'"
echo $'pipearg1\npipearg2' | ./command.pl
echo "====================================="
echo ""

echo "====================================="
echo "T07: echo -e with newline: '..\n..'"
echo -e "pipearg1\npipearg2" | ./command.pl
echo "====================================="
echo ""

echo "====================================="
echo "T08: 2 cli args via HEREDOC 'cmd <<EOF ... EOF'"
./command.pl <<EOF
arghd1
arghd2
EOF
echo "====================================="
echo ""

echo "====================================="
echo "T09: 2 cli args via process substitution 'cmd < <(...cmds...)'"
./command.pl < <(echo argps1; echo argps2)
echo "====================================="
echo ""

echo "====================================="
echo "T10: T03 + T09"
./command.pl argv1 argv2 < <(echo argps1; echo argps2)
echo "====================================="
echo ""
```

#### Output from tests.bash

The `tests.bash` script is designed to run 11 different tests, ranging from using HEREDOCS, to subshells, to passing command line arguments. It also uses these in combinations to fully test the Perl script, `command.pl`.

```
$ ./tests.bash 


=====================================
T00: no input

USAGE
=====
#1:  ./command.pl <arg1>..<argN>
#2:  <commands> | ./command.pl
#3:  <commands> | ./command.pl <arg1>..<argN>

=====================================

=====================================
T01: 2 args w/ pipe via cmd list '(..) | ...' aka. subshell

STDIN ARGS
==========
pipearg1
pipearg2

=====================================

=====================================
T02: 2 args w/ pipe via inline group '{..} | ...' aka. code block

STDIN ARGS
==========
pipearg1
pipearg2

=====================================

=====================================
T03: 2 cli args 'cmd A1 A2'

ARGV ARGS
=========
argv1
argv2

=====================================

=====================================
T04: T01 + T03

STDIN ARGS
==========
pipearg1
pipearg2


ARGV ARGS
=========
argv1
argv2

=====================================

=====================================
T05: T02 + T03

STDIN ARGS
==========
pipearg1
pipearg2


ARGV ARGS
=========
argv1
argv2

=====================================

=====================================
T06: echo with newline: $'..\n..'

STDIN ARGS
==========
pipearg1
pipearg2

=====================================

=====================================
T07: echo -e with newline: '..\n..'

STDIN ARGS
==========
pipearg1
pipearg2

=====================================

=====================================
T08: 2 cli args via HEREDOC 'cmd <<EOF ... EOF'

STDIN ARGS
==========
arghd1
arghd2

=====================================

=====================================
T09: 2 cli args via process substitution 'cmd < <(...cmds...)'

STDIN ARGS
==========
argps1
argps2

=====================================

=====================================
T10: T03 + T09

STDIN ARGS
==========
argps1
argps2


ARGV ARGS
=========
argv1
argv2

=====================================
```

#### References

- [Back to back Pipes into a Command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171150/back-to-back-pipes-into-a-command)

Answer (score 1):

You can add input from `STDIN` at the end of `@ARGV`,

```
push @ARGV, <STDIN> unless -t STDIN;
```

Comment: `if -p STDIN` [also works](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) instead of `unless -t STDIN`